# Error in Bazel Build Installation of Tensorflow From Source

Tags: python, tensorflow

Recently, I have attempted to install the TensorFlow module from source on a MacOS computer. I have, so far, progressed by installing Python 3.6, the TensorFlow pip package dependencies (I have already installed pip) and installing Bazel using the commands given on their website. I configured the source tree, first with Python 3.6 and later with 2.7 after learning of this error. However, soon after, when I entered the command:

```
bazel build -config=opt//tensorflow/tools/pip_package:build_pip_package
```

I received this message:

```
Starting local Bazel server and connecting to it...
INFO: Invocation ID: 2028ac42-5ccd-4c28-9156-e7d547c89263
ERROR:          /private/var/tmp/_bazel_surengrigorian/c9e5c7de228d990fbf93866f2deac188/external/local_config_cc/BUILD:58:5: in apple_cc_toolchain rule 
@local_config_cc//:cc-compiler-watchos_arm64_32: Xcode version must   be specified to use an Apple CROSSTOOL. If your Xcode version has    changed recently, try: "bazel clean --expunge" to re-run Xcode   configuration
ERROR: Analysis of target '//tensorflow/tools/pip_package:build_pip_package' failed; build   aborted: Analysis of target '@local_config_cc//:cc-compiler-   watchos_arm64_32' failed; build aborted
INFO: Elapsed time: 11.538s
INFO: 0 processes.
FAILED: Build did NOT complete successfully (171 packages loaded,    3109 targets\
configured)
    currently loading: tensorflow/core/kernels
    Fetching @swig; fetching 4s
    Fetching @grpc; fetching
```

Thank you for any assistance you can provide as to how to fix this error.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. I solved it by downgrading the Bazel version. In my case, Bazel 21.0 did not work. Reinstalling bazel to 18.0 works fine. https://github.com/bazelbuild/bazel/releases/tag/0.18.0

Comment: I've also had issues with `18.0`, I've found that `15.0` works best, in case there are still errors.

Comment: Bazel sometimes can be funny. Everybody has their own issue, downgrading or upgrading version sometimes is the best solution lol. https://medium.com/windmill-engineering/bazel-is-the-worst-build-system-except-for-all-the-others-b369396a9e26

Answer (score 0):

Downgrading to Bazel 0.29.1 worked for me.